# JavaFx how to set NumberAxis Cyclic?

Tags: javafx

I need to create a ScatterChart with X axis as angle.

The X axis need to have those values:

```
[180, 225, 270, 315, 0, 45, 90, 135, 180]  (tickUnit = 45).
```

I can create the axsis like:

```
NumberAxis(-180,180, 45)
```

but it gives me:

```
[-180, -135, -90, -45, 0, 45, 90, 135, 180]
```

How can I start the NumberAxis from -180 with tickUnit = 45 and end up to 180 (of course using Cyclic...)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tickLabelFormatter` to change the way the ticks are labelled:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class CyclicChart extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(-180, 180, 45);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(-1,1,0.1);
        ScatterChart<Number, Number> chart = new ScatterChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                double value = object.doubleValue();
                if (value < 0) {
                    value = value + (1 + (int)(-value / 360)) * 360 ;
                }
                return String.format("%.1f", value % 360);
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                // Not used
                return null;
            }

        });

        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        chart.getData().add(series);
        double min = xAxis.getLowerBound();
        double range = xAxis.getUpperBound() - min ;
        int numPoints = 90 ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= numPoints ; i++) {
            double a = min + i * range / numPoints ;
            series.getData().add(new Data<>(a, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a))));
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(chart, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that the actual values being used in the graph are still in the range `[-180,180]`, but the display forces them to be displayed in the range `[0,360]`.